# Is there a pure Erlang cryptography library with support for AES?

Tags: encryption, erlang

I need to use AES encryption in my embedded Erlang application, but OpenSSL is unavailable for my target system and so the crypto library from OTP can't be built. I probably could cross-compile OpenSSL as well, but I would prefer a pure Erlang solution to remove another dependency. Does one exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looked at this a while ago and found no nice solution other than OpenSSL/crypto. Sorry.
Unless someone made a new library recently but I haven't heard about it since then.

It's more likely that someone has already solved the problem of easily installing OpenSSL on your target system. Would focus my energy on that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The crypto module has been OpenSSL dependent for a long time. The pure Erlang version might not be impossible, but it will be very very slow and will not be practical in use.